# Having an issue with a pattern match character in my create user action

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to pattern match on the result of inserting a new user to the database.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the below code, am I using the wrong keys for `->` possibly?

I have copied and pasted the code from the phoenix book but it still doesn't work.

Very confused as to what the issue is here?  I am sure it is something very tiny!

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.name} created!") 
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

I am getting an error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/user_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:24: unhandled operator ->
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Comment: It is `case Repo.insert(changeset) do`. You missed the word `case`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [Justin Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773228/justin-wood), there is a missing `case` keyword.

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.name} created!") 
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```